# How do you get 2 render layers from an exr file?

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-layers, render-passes, .exr

I am compositing a scene with 2 render layers. I saved it as an image sequence of EXR files so that I can close the program. However, after compositing, the Exr doesnt keep data from separate render layers. I have different render passes in the layers and need them to stay separate.

Question:
How do I get the render layer data from the EXR so that I can composite either render layer separately?

Here is a picture

Notice how the EXR import have anything indicating separate render layers
Forgive my horrible handwriting, and thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: How did you save the render layers as *.exr? It could be that the information is indeed missing.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. I used the EXR filetype, directed the data to a file, and then hit render. I assumed that the only reason that I have separate render layers is because I haven't closed the program yet.

Comment: Wait, was I supposed to use Multilayer Exr, rather than normal EXR?

Comment: For comp later multilayer is what you want, yes

Comment: Well, I learned that I need to use multilayer exrs when dealing with render layers, and I am an idiot :) Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can also render to multiple EXRs. One way to set that up is to create File output node, plug it with whatever needed set to simple EXRs and render. That way you can cut down space required for storage since EXRs with individual passes will need less

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I probably wont use it because I don't want to risk rendering for another 18 hours lol. Put all 8 cores at 100% power.